# I want to do Time series forecasting on daily ATM transaction data

Tags: r, time-series

I have a data for ATM transaction on a daily basis and this data represent a seasonal variation in weekend and holidays.

data structure like this

```
trans_date  tot_amount  Weekend Holiday_flag
01/10/2013  164800  0   0
02/10/2013  205900  0   1
03/10/2013  215600  0   0
04/10/2013  228600  0   0
05/10/2013  410200  1   0
```

I used `arima()` function in R to forecast the next one month data but I am not getting better forecast.

I am confusing to capture seasonal variation in my data.

I have to select the ARIMA order from ACF and PACF plot but I have some confusion to capture seasonal order from this graph.

So please advise me how can I select the right ARIMA model for my data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you tried a "simple" tbats approach with multiple seasonalities yet as explained here: [link](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/dailydata/)

I would suggest you are getting familiar with the `forecast` package of Rob J Hyndman. There is also a really good book from him that is available online for free [link](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/)

As for your Arima approach i would suggest you use the `auto.arima()` function in the forecast package. There you can include dummy variables including Fourier terms (as explained in the first link). Here is another example for that method [link](http://blog.pivotal.io/data-science-pivotal/products/forecasting-time-series-data-with-multiple-seasonal-periods)

IrishStat is for sure not wrong when he says that it is hard to make such forecasts "simply" with R - but (based on my own i experience) it is possible to get some good/decent results.

**Update:**

```
#load your data into R
require('data.table')
dat <- fread('data.csv') #only the date and the amount column
setnames(dat, c(1,2), c('date', 'amount'))
dat$date <- as.Date(dat$date, '%d/%m/%y') #transform date column into real dates    
dat[,Weekday := weekdays(date)] # create a column for the weekdays

#create a time series
dat.ts <- ts(dat$amount, frequency=7)

require('forecast')

#fit a tbats model, forecast 30days, and plot it
fm.tbats <- tbats(dat.ts)
fc.tbats <- forecast(fm.tbats, h=30)
plot(fc.tbats)

#fit an arima model with a fourier term, forecast 30days and plot it
fm.arima <- auto.arima(dat.ts, xreg=fourier(dat.ts, 3))
fc.arima <- forecast(fm.arima, xreg=fourierf(dat.ts,3,30), h=30)
plot(fc.arima)

#fit an arima model with dummies for day of the week
dummies <- cbind(model.matrix(~dat$Weekday)[,2:7])
colnames(dummies) <- c('Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat','Sun')
fm.arima.d <- auto.arima(dat$amount, xreg=dummies)
```

That is how you can use `auto.arima()` and `tbats()` to work with your data. I am not saying anything about if it is good/fits your data/whatever - i just wanted to show you how to use it in the right way. When your dataset is less then a year you can also test other functions in the `forecast` package like `stl()` for example. When you type `?stl()` you will see the help file for the function which normally includes a simple example on how it works. I highly recommend you to have a look at the book from Rob J Hyndman.

Comment: I would be interested in investigating/disproving your assertion of getting good/decent results with Fourier approaches as my experience tells me otherwise . Perhaps you might want to pursue this with me and perhaps we can both learn something.

Comment: @random Dude i tried forecasting using auto.arima() function but it give error to Unable to fit final model using maximum likelihood. AIC value approximated.

Comment: After giving some optional in auto.arima() it fitted model but its  not giving forecasting value correct, means i getting this value are same for all h=10.

Comment: i also tried tbats and fourier series but not getting satisfied results.

Comment: I trying with arima function in R with seasonality and also add dummy variable in that for weekdays beacause so many seasonality present in my data in weekdays and weekdays

Comment: wekdays and weekend

Comment: i found good result with this approach and also model passed by statistical  test like box.test and residual checking. but some variation are there with actual and forecasted data.

Comment: @Shahnawaz if you add some sample data and your R code (how you used `auto.arima()` and `tbats()`) i will have a look.

Comment: i used sample_arima<-arima(sample_ts,order=c(1,1,4),seasonal = list(order=c(1,1,4),period=6),xreg=sample_xreg) this command for fitting arima model. sample_xreg is weekdays variable Mon-Sat

Comment: Can you upload some sample data as well?

Comment: sample data available on this link.....https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HO-_c0M-YWD5lKT66RnpBMKYk_DfcnhZaedALyW1qSc/pubhtml?gid=0&single=true

Comment: please suggest your idea on that. It will really appreciated...thanks

Comment: Hi RandomDude. Have you look that link for sample data?  please give your suggestion on that. It will really very appreciated.Thanks in Advance

Comment: Check my original post, i updated it a while ago.

Comment: Thanks RandomDude for updating. I have one question here ,why we are not including  all 7 weekdays here?like Mon to Sun

Comment: Is there also required to add holiday dummy variable also to capture the seasonality

Comment: With 6 dummy variables you can represent 7 dummies since when you put all your 6 dummies to 0 -> you choose the 7th.  You can also read about it here: [link](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/5/2) Adding holiday dummies can improve the quality of your model and thereby also the quality of capturing the seasonality, but it depends highly on your data and the question if the holidays have an impact...

Comment: You can mark your question as answered when you are satisfied.

Comment: Thank you very much RandomDude for your valuable output. It's very helpful for me.

Comment: One more question please i have some doubts. My ques is:-Suppose in my data (7 months data) there are total 8 holidays so i need to create 8 holiday variable or other else? please suggest me your views on that.

Comment: Yes for 8 holidays you would need 8 dummies +  for lead and lag effects more dummies. E.g. you want to check 8 holidays including the 3 days before and after each holiday -> 8 + 24 + 24 = 56 dummies

Comment: can you give me a real life example or share some link if you have for my better understanding...thanks

Comment: Well in the exact same way than we created the weekday dummies. You need to create a column for each holiday as well as for each day before/after that you are interested in. There are plenty of posts that deal with that topic, just use the search... e.g. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19138309/create-indicator-variables-of-holidays-from-a-date-column)

Comment: Hi RandomDude, I was trying to do forecasting on Daily ATM cash forecasting by your mentioned above method.i also add dummy variable in arima() function. But forecast value and actual value could not match,some variation is present between them. So please suggest me what can we do for that.

Comment: I request you to try to fit model on mention data. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HO-_c0M-YWD5lKT66RnpBMKYk_DfcnhZaedALyW1qSc/pubhtml?gid=0&single=true

Comment: Please post your R code as an update to your original question. What do you mean by "forecast value and actual value could not match"? maybe you can post a plot with the forecasted value and the actual value...

Comment: This is the R code which i used for forecasting.................................

Comment: This is the link for datas set....In sheet one the  data used from sep 2013 to feb 2014  and in sheet two data for mar 2014 for comparing forecast value.... cahttps://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-LJhxzfpMkeCwLf129D9-q5ZkGhISqrDQWCw30UE9TE/pubhtml

Comment: how can i share with you my R code

Comment: bellow is the link for R code .... https://docs.google.com/document/d/1mPo0D-iTK5d_b0W5gG2lBmMA95__eG825fFo2yrSyIg/pub

Comment: Any output RandomDude??/

Comment: *I am not an expert so maybe you did the right thing and i am just not seeing it! How do you come to that exact arima.model (order and seasonal)? Have you checked for other seasonalities in the data? How are other methods like tbats and lm with dummies in compare to your arima model? How do you evaluate the forecast accuracy?

Comment: from ACF and PACF graph i am choosing arima model because my data not be stationary and i need to take difference by 1 and difference by 7 due to weekly seasonality. Yes i am check the other seasonality but i am not seeing any other seasonality. Forecast accuracy evaluated by residual plot and RMSe

Comment: How is the ACF and PACF graph of the residuals? Is auto.arima() choosing the same model than you?

Answer (score 0):

Selecting the "right" ARIMA model for data like this is not the preferred choice . You might want to look at an alternative variable-driven example that uses daily atm machine data http://www.autobox.com/cms/index.php/afs-university/intro-to-forecasting/doc_download/53-capabilities-presentation starting at slide 45. The whole idea is to incorporate ( as needed ) daily effects,weekly effects . monthly effects , specific week-in-month effects , specific day-in=month effects , activity around known events like holidays , long-weekend effects , Friday before holiday events , Monday after holiday events , level-shifts , time trends , pulses and changes in day-of-the-week effects and any causal variables that you might like to suggest . You can possibly program these exploratory activities yourself but it might be tedious. I was one of the developers of AUTOBOX and so state for transparency and for any kudos you might like to send my way (grin).

Comment: But i want to do this forecasting in R using time series forecasting.I think i need to add dummy variable in xreg  in arima function. So please help me do this forecasting in R

Comment: In order to add these dummy variables you need to know which ones are important e.g. how many days before and after each holiday are important or how many different trends there are. Once you figure those out then you can use R .

Comment: yes i figure out that from ACF and PACF plot and i found that mostly variation are in weekends. Means transaction are more on Friday and  saturday and least on Sunday i want to add dummy variable on weekend so please suggest how to add this dummy variable in my model

Comment: I used ARIMA model with seasonal difference bellow are the r code for it. w1_diff_arima<-arima(p1_ts,order=c(0,1,3),seasonal=list(order=c(0,1,3),xreg=xtrain,periods=7)).  p1_ts is my time series data conatin tot_transaction amount and i am using xreg function in arima for adding the regressor. xtrain is the combination of  holiday_flag and weekend. Weekend :-0 indicate no weekend and 1 indicate saturday and sunday i.e weekend. and holiday flag :- 0 no holiday and 1: there is holiday

Comment: i took period =7 because more variation are seems in weekend.                 I am getting the nearest results but not actual forecast. some variation are there. i got bellow result using above arima function.

Comment: Call:
arima(x = p1_ts, order = c(0, 1, 3), seasonal = list(order = c(0, 1, 3), xreg = xtrain, 
    periods = 7))

Coefficients:
          ma1      ma2      ma3     sma1     sma2    sma3
      -0.7589  -0.0651  -0.1729  -0.8497  -0.1117  0.0553
s.e.   0.1033   0.0860   0.0632   0.0675   0.0852  0.0718

sigma^2 estimated as 4.347e+10:  log likelihood = -3590.95,  aic = 7195.9

Comment: but in the above results i am not getting the result for weekend and holiday variable

Comment: The reason you are not finding holidays to be significant is probably because you are A) combining all holidays into 1 variable AND B) one needs to incorporate lead and lag effects of the holiday not just the holiday . Additionally pulses if untreated increase the error variance thus downwards biasing the t value for all model coefficients. R is probably not suitable for your problem because the specific form of your model needs to be found not specified a priori thus the need for better approaches.

Comment: so what kind of approach to be used in this probelem

Comment: please suggest me which method i can use to achieve my goal ASAP

Comment: i am trying so much but i am not getting the desired output.....

Comment: can we use fourier series to forecast this problem

Comment: No you can't use fourier because of the reasons I gave 3 hours ago. If you wish we can take this conversation offline . send me an email at my contact info